# watir-webdriver and radio buttons styled as jquery buttonset, confusing behavior when clicking

Tags: jquery, ruby, cucumber, radio-button, watir-webdriver

I'm using watir-webdriver to interact with radio buttons in Firefox that are styled as a jQuery buttonset.

```
  <label for="radioButtonSet">Radio Buttons</label>
  <div id="radioButtonSet">
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio"/><label for="radio1">Choice 1</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio"/><label for="radio2">Choice 2</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio"/><label for="radio3">Choice 3</label>
  </div>
```

The relevant js:

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#radioButtonSet" ).buttonset();
  });
```

Now, what this turns into is actually a hidden set of radio buttons, each with a <label> that's got listeners on it to interact with the corresponding radio button. Hacky but ehh. Anyway, I want to make my Cucumber step definitions to appear 'agnostic' with regards to whether we're dealing with a basic (unstyled) set of radio buttons, or a jQuery buttonset. The step of interest is as follows:

```
When /^I click on the (.+ button)$/ do |button|
  get_on_page(@current_page,button).click
end
```

I'm using page object models, so get_on_page is defined as...

```
def get_on_page (page_object, element_on_page) 
  page_object.send(element_on_page.downcase.gsub(" ","_"))
end
```

In the interest of full disclosure, because I wanted steps like "and the middle radio button is selected" to likewise be jQuery agnostic, I've extended Watir::Label so that I can use it to check if whatever button it's for happens to be checked.

```
class Watir::Label
  attr_accessor :for, :browser

  #For cases where the label is a "skin" over a checkbox or radio button.
  #Finds the checkbox or radio button that this Label is for and interrogates it.
  #Requires that @browser is set to the current active browser instance
  def checked?
    @input = @browser.checkbox(:id => self.for)
    if (not @input.exists?) then
      @input = @browser.radio(:id => self.for)
    end
    @input.checked?
  end
end
```

Anyway, in irb (command line) everything works as expected. See here:

```
irb(main):370:0> @middle_radio_button = @browser.label(:for => "radio2")
=> #<Watir::Label:0x5b6635c2 located=false selector={:for=>"radio2", :tag_name=>"label"}>
irb(main):371:0> @middle_radio_button.browser = @browser
=> #<Watir::Browser:0x..fb560d81a url="file:///C:/Users/dsharkov/git/html-template/ShowCase.html" title="Showcase">
irb(main):372:0> @middle_radio_button.for = "radio2"
=> "radio2"
irb(main):373:0> @middle_radio_button.click
=> []
irb(main):374:0> @middle_radio_button.checked?
=> true
```

I can click the <label> and then see whether its radio button is checked. And yes I've visually confirmed on the active browser window that the label gets clicked and all that fun stuff.

So, here's the problem. I CAN NOT get this to work as expected when I am running my Cucumber features! Here's the scenario:

```
Scenario: radio buttons styled as jQuery toggle buttons
    Given I am on the Showcase page
      And I click on the middle radio button
     Then the middle radio button is selected
      And the left radio button is not selected
```

The other step definition of interest is the "is selected" one, I guess, so here's that:

```
Then /^the (.+) is (not )?(?:checked|selected)$/ do |checkbox_or_radio,not_checked|
  @checkbox = get_on_page(@current_page,checkbox_or_radio)
  if (not_checked == "not ") then
    @checkbox.checked?.should_not be_true
  else
    @checkbox.checked?.should be_true
  end
end
```

Here's what I get:

```
  Scenario: radio buttons styled as jQuery toggle buttons # features\accessing_common_elements.feature:54
    Given I am on the Showcase page                       # features/step_definitions/common_steps.rb:3
    And I click on the middle radio button                # features/step_definitions/common_steps.rb:19
    Then the middle radio button is selected              # features/step_definitions/common_steps.rb:85
      expected false to be true (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
      ./features/step_definitions/common_steps.rb:90:in `/^the (.+) is (not )?(?:checked|selected)$/'
      features\accessing_common_elements.feature:57:in `Then the middle radio button is selected'
    And the left radio button is not selected             # features/step_definitions/common_steps.rb:85
```

This makes me sad. I have visually confirmed that all that happens to the buttonset is the button I'm interested in clicking simply gets highlighted as if it's being hovered over, which looks different.

And here's what makes me even more sad -- when I change my step definition to this:

```
When /^I click on the (.+ button)$/ do |button|
  get_on_page(@current_page,button).click
  get_on_page(@current_page,button).click  
end
```

Everything is happy and green. That is not cool! Clicking twice is not the same as clicking once, nor is it the same as doubleclicking, so I am really confused about this. What may be the underlying issue here? This would be a little easier to comprehend if I weren't seeing it work "correctly" through irb. I also don't think it's a race condition because I've added a `Watir::Wait.until{...}` after the single click and that merely timed out.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: could this just be timing? is there a slight delay between when the label is clicked and the actual state of the hidden control is altered by the javascript?   If you make your IRB steps into a script and run it 'at speed' as it were, does it still work for you?

Comment: I did just as you suggested... and sure enough it's the same as when I run it through Cucumber. Basically what's happening visually is a "mouseover" as far as I can tell based on the jQuery label's animation, despite sending a click. What's interesting is that if I end the script at that, the click never actually occurs. So it's not quite a timing issue as far as I can tell. The event just doesn't fire, or seemingly the wrong one does...

Comment: UPDATE: if I run the script that finds the label and clicks it after having played around with that control on the page a bit, it works. If I visit the page for the first time and then run the script, it fails and ends with that "mouseover" highlight. So it's as if something isn't loaded in time... at least that's how it "looks"

Comment: More awesomeness:  
`@middle_radio_button.fire_event("onmouseover")` and the first `@middle_radio_button.click` both seem to do the same thing. The second `@middle_radio_button.click` seems to do the same thing as 
`@middle_radio_button.fire_event("onclick")`. So, I can "solve" this conundrum by doing a `fire_event("onclick")` from the get-go. Anything in terms of "best practices" that I should keep in mind regarding this?

Comment: Having not worked with this exact control, I couldn't say.  As far as I know .click  is actually firing a series of events, designed to be somewhat of an analog of the 'organic' action which would fire onmouseover as you moved the pointer over the control, followed by the onclick etc.   So manybe the client side code is doing something at onmouseover like changing a visual, and is too busy to see the rapidly following click event..   firing onclick probably bypasses that and gets straight to causing the i've been clicked action to take effect.

Comment: In the meantime I suggest creating an 'answer' that describes exactly how you fixed this so the next person to come along can benefit from your experience.  If you know the specific jquery control being used, putting that name in the question 'title' would be good also.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for your insights, Chuck. And "buttonset" is precisely the jquery control being used so that's already in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "solution" to this ended up being changing the step definition that was used for clicking on a button.

Original:

```
When /^I click on the (.+ button)$/ do |button|
  get_on_page(@current_page,button).click
end
```

New and improved:

```
When /^I click on the (.+ [Bb]utton)$/ do |button|
  get_on_page(@current_page,button).fire_event("onclick")
end
```

As Chuck mentions above in the comments, a `.click` will result in multiple events firing, but what's of interest in this case is really what happens in response to an "onclick" event, so this rewrite is sufficient. At least for the purposes of this situation.